# Showing that $\zeta(s) = 0$ implies $\Re(s) = \frac12$, where $\zeta$ is the zeta function of an elliptic curve

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, elliptic-curves, zeta-functions

Let $a$ be a constant, let $q=p^n$ be a prime power, and define $$\zeta(s) = \frac{q^{2s}-aq^s+q}{(q^s-1)(q^s-q)}.$$

> **Question.** To show that if $\zeta(s)=0$, then $\Re(s) = \frac12$.

Here is my attempt so far:

Noice that for all $s$, $\zeta(s) = \zeta(1-s)$, thus a zero of $\zeta$ satisfies
$$(q^s)^2 - a(q^s)+q=0 \quad \text{and} \quad (q^{1-s})^2 - a(q^{1-s})+q=0.$$
Thus $q^s$ and $q^{1-s}$ are the zeros of the quadratic $z^2 - az + q$. For any quadratic, $\alpha$ is a root if and only if the conjugate $\bar\alpha$ is also a root.  Moreover,  $\overline {q^{1-s}} = q^{1-\bar s}$ and $\overline{q^s} = q^{\bar s}$.  Therefore one of the following must be true:
            \begin{align*}
            q^s &= q^{1-s}, \\
            q^s = q^{\bar s} \quad &\text{and} \quad q^{1-s} = q^{1-\bar s},\\
            q^s = q^{1-\bar s} \quad &\text{and} \quad q^{1-s} = q^{\bar s}.
        \end{align*}
            The first and third cases clearly imply that $\Re(s)=\frac12$. But in the second case, all we can deduce is that $s$ is real.

How can I show that $\Re(s) = \frac12$ in this case also?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Why don't you change $\zeta$ to $f$ ?

Comment: @reuns Because this is the [$\zeta$ function](http://people.reed.edu/~jerry/361/lectures/zetaec.pdf) of an elliptic curve. This is equivalent to the Riemann hypothesis for functional fields, not just for clickbait!

Comment: @ċuqlajta My guess is the downvoters did not understand your question and assumed it was a spam question about the Riemann Hypothesis. I wouldn't worry too much. Your question is fine as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a$ is real. The roots of $X^2-aX+q$ are $\frac{a\pm \sqrt{a^2-4q}}{2}$, iff $a^2-4q\le 0$ then the two roots are complex conjugate so they have the same absolute value $q^{1/2}$. If $a^2-4q> 0$ then the result isn't true. That's why the [Hasse bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse%27s_theorem_on_elliptic_curves) is important for elliptic curves (its generalization to higher genus curves is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weil_conjectures)

Comment: For my case, $x^2 - ax + q$ is actually the quadratic polynomial satisfied by $\phi_q$, the Frobenius endomorphism of the elliptic curve $y^2 = x^3 + ax + b$ ($a,b\in\mathbb F_p$).  Does this somehow help us to prove this?

Comment: Absolutely @ċuqlajta! The Hasse-Weil bound (for elliptic curves) specifically says that $a^2\le 4q$! Mind you, the $a$ in the equation of the elliptic curve is unrelated to the $a$ in the $\zeta$-function.

Comment: Guess what the title of the next section in my notes is - "The Hasse bound"! I should have kept on reading before starting the exercises. Thanks!